# Laravel error when trying to access user inside Service's register() method

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

Inside my service provider, I want to choose which class to bind based on user's settings.

The problem is that I cannot access the user inside the register() method, I am getting an error saying "Class [Hash] does not exist"

Comment: you don't have access to the session at that point, you don't have sessions until the request goes through the middleware stack and hits the StartSession middleware, the framework hasn't completed booting yet and other providers haven't finished registering yet ... can you provide your code

Comment: All I want is to bind a class based on user's settings. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: it would depend when that abstract would need to be resolved (when it is first resolved from the container) but you can bind a closure and in there you could try to pick which implementation to return

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that. Is what I am asking that really complicated?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access laravel services within `register` but you can use **php superglobals**

you can retrieve user custom cookies with:

```
$_COOKIE["foo"];
```

but when you want to save the cookie in users browser you have to use the php's `setcookie()` because laravel's Cookie Service **Encrypt** The Value and you cant access Decryption within `register` method.

```
\setcookie("foo", "bar", time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```